# Loop repeats indefinitely after break (c++)

Tags: c++, while-loop

My problem here is when the loop is broken after the user indicates they're done, the program then begins to print the last input infinitely.  What's going on here?  I've tried using break, return 0, setting loop = a, all results in the same thing.  On a program earlier I used a for loop (used break) and it terminated just fine.

**Note:** *This post is **NOT** up for syntax corrections*, this is just a fragment, and the code runs fine until I terminate the loop. I'm wanting to know what's causing this to happen with a while-loop specifically.

Edit: Nevermind, figured out what was going on.  When attempting to end the loop there was a datatype error (as you can see, we only receive input for two variables, both of which are ints), which caused the loop to the start repeating the last valid datatype entered.  So my question is why does this happen with a data type error? 
`

```
while (loop != "a")
{
    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "\nEnter the second number: ";
    cin >> input2;

    cout << input1 << '\t' << input2 << '\n';

    if (loop == "|")
    {
        break;
    }
}`
```

Comment: You never change the value of `loop` variable.
Did you mean to put `loop = input[0] `?

Comment: Like I said earlier, this is just a fragment.  I didn't post the part of the code that assigns a value to loop.  I'm wanting to know why when the while-loop gets terminated it begins to print the last input results infinitely.

Comment: So let’s get this straight. You’re showing us a fragment that doesn’t contain all the operations being performed (or even declarations of variables so we can know the type) and asking why it doesn’t work as you expect!?!

Comment: I would suggest you try to extract the unnecessary parts of your code until you cannot remove anything, and the problem still persists. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (minimal, complete, verifiable example)

Comment: Well yes, the entire code isn't needed for my question. @AdamKotwasinski Thanks, I already figured out what was causing the issue but I'll give that link  a looksee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you entered a wrong data type into 'cin'. This makes cin fail and it repeats the last acceptable value in the command prompt. Nothing to do with the loop. If you try it outside of the loop you'll see the same thing happen.

It's good practice to do the following:

```
while (!(cin >> input))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cout << "Bad input. Try again: ";
}
```

so if cin fails - it will clear the fail status, ignore the last input and ask the user to enter his input again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of **loop** with in the block of while loop according to your condition if **loop=="a"** or **loop =="|"** then while loop will be terminated.
In the given code of you the value of **loop** is not changing therefore while loop will run infinite.

I hope you can understand.

Comment: Not what I asked for

Comment: then debug the code there will be some minor mistake in the program or line of code in which value of loop is changing is not at appropriate place.